# Using CSVWriter to Enforce String Length

Tags: c#, .net-core, etl, csvhelper

I am currently working on a project to pull JSON data from a SaaS tool (through an API) into a SQL database. Eventually, this data will be used for reporting purposes (as a data source in Tableau).

Here is the overall process flow:

1. Pull raw JSON data (using `RestSharp`).
2. Convert each record to POCO (using `JSON.NET` + `json2csharp` to generate POCO classes).
3. Add each record from step 2 to a `List<MyClassExample>`.
4. Write all records to CSV file (using `CSVHelper`).
5. Import CSV file to SQL database.

**Note:** These steps are repeated for *each object*. There are about 10 objects, with each one having anywhere between **10 to 150** fields (columns). All POCO attributes are strings (*is this bad?*)

**The issue**: I am getting truncation errors because I am not sure the best way to define/enforce a size limit on each column. Some of the columns are free-text paragraph fields - so the "max size" of each column *might* change, which is leading to truncation errors. There is no documentation on the web-API side that guarantees/defines a specific schema for the data.

How can I define a schema/max length for each column BEFORE step 5 so that I don't run into truncation errors?

I know I can define max lengths on a per-field basis within a POCO definition: but I have ~10 POCOs with hundreds of fields. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You are putting the check in the wrong location.  You can't prevent the errors once the User enters wrong data.  Human Enter data is prone to typo errors which cannot be fixed in software.  Suppose one field was a credit card number and the exception you were getting was due to a person entering a bad credit card number.  You cannot fix the issue.  The check needs to be done when the data is entered.

Comment: The error is not in the data being invalid but rather that the data can be longer than anticipated. For example: if I have a free-paragraph field called "Last Comment" and run this program today, the longest might be 2500 characters, but if someone enters a new comment today and I run this again, it might be 2700 characters, which causes a truncation error. What is the best way to fix this, keeping in mind I have no control over validating/restricting data at the source (where users enter). I just need to be able to handle scenarios where max length of column might've changed overnight.

Comment: I do not like CSVHelper.  It is a library that is not needed.  You can do the same with a few lines of c# and you have better control on filtering the data (like restricting the length in this case).  I'm not sure where the exception is occurring. If it is in the CSVHelper it is not helping.

Comment: It sounds like you have created the SQL tables using the longest value of the data you have so far.  How do you want to handle 2700 characters when the last longest was 2500 characters?  Should CsvWriter throw an error so you know to update the SQL table to now allow 2700 characters, or should CsvWriter simply truncate the data to 2500 characters? Do you want to be able to add attributes to your POCO classes to indicate the `MaxLength` of each column? If not, how do you plan on getting the `MaxLength`?

Comment: I suppose that's what I'm trying to figure out. What are best practices/standards around handling this problem? I wouldn't mind adding attributes to my POCO classes but with over 1000 attributes (across 10 classes) it seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to query the database to find the max lengths of the text columns.  The following uses Dapper to query a SQL Server database, but you should be able to modify the example to work with other ORMs or database providers.  This example throws an exception if the text is longer than the property's max length, but you could modify it to truncate the string instead.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true";
        var sql = @"
SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName, 
  CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as CharacterMaximumLength 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL";

        List<MaxLength> maxLengths;

        using (var db = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            maxLengths = db.Query<MaxLength>(sql, new { TableName = "MyClassExample" }).AsList();
        }

        var records = new List<MyClassExample>
        {
            new MyClassExample {Id = 1, PropertyName = "First"},
            new MyClassExample {Id = 2, PropertyName = "Second is certainly longer than the 50 characters maximum length."}
        };

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            var classMap = new DefaultClassMap<MyClassExample>();
            classMap.AutoMap(); 
            classMap.RegisterMaxLengths(maxLengths);
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(classMap);

            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyClassExample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class MaxLengthConverter : StringConverter
{
    private readonly int _maxLength = 0;
    public MaxLengthConverter(int maxLength)
    {
        _maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value is string text)
            if (text.Length > _maxLength)
            {
                var message =   $"The text with length {text.Length} exceeds the maximum allowed length of {_maxLength}.\r\n" +
                                $"    Text: '{text}'\r\n" +
                                $"    Property: {memberMapData.Member?.Name}\r\n" +
                                $"    TypeConverter: '{memberMapData.TypeConverter?.GetType().FullName}'";
                throw new TypeConverterException(this, memberMapData, value, row.Context, message);
            }

        return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }
}

public class MaxLength
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int CharacterMaximumLength { get; set; }
}

public static class CsvHelpExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterMaxLengths<T>(this ClassMap<T> map, IEnumerable<MaxLength> maxLengths)
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var maxLength = maxLengths.Where(m => m.ColumnName.ToLower() == property.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (maxLength != null)
                map.Map(typeof(T), property, true).TypeConverter(new MaxLengthConverter(maxLength.CharacterMaximumLength));
        }
    }
}
```